# Post Request to Google API with OAuth2.0

Tags: laravel, guzzle, google-oauth, google-indexing-api

I want to make a post request to Google Indexing API with OAuth2.0 authentication.

https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart

I want to do this with Guzzle package in Laravel 5.4

```
(new GuzzleHttp\Client)->post(URL, PARAMS);
```

In Google documents, they provide a PHP package to do this. But I want to achieve this by Guzzle and Laravel. Is there any way to send token parameters by them?

Thanks.

Comment: what 'token parameters' are you trying to pass? i can't quickly find anything on that page or its children called that.

Comment: Overall I don't know how to use indexing API authentication params. I can't find the right thing on google docs